# Compiling udis86 with visual studio 2019 gives me an unresolved external symbol

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I'm trying to compile an UEFI driver, that uses udis86(https://github.com/vmt/udis86) with the `__UD_STANDALONE__` preprocessor definition and the /NODEFAULTLIB linker option set.
This gives me this error
[image: error]

I have tried to set the `_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE` preprocessor definition, like replied to some similar questions to mine, but it just changes the error to
[image: error2]

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this error ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could take a standalone `vsnprintf` implementation from somewhere to satisfy the dependency.

e.g.
https://github.com/MrBad/vsnprintf

or the Linux kernel one?
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/lib/vsprintf.c

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by using the VCPKG version of udis86, but I still don't know why this error was appearing.